Change encoding of all files in a Visual studio project
I know how to change the encoding of a single file in Visual Studio, that is, by going to "Save as..." -> "Save with encoding" and choosing the encoding. However, I got an old C++ codebase with hundreds of source files. Is there a way to batch re-encode them (specifically, to UTF-8)? I am aware of .editorconfig and similar editor settings, but those only affect newly created files.

As far as I know, programs like visual studio, visual code, notepad++ do not support this feature. In my case I used such a python script:
import os
import chardet

def convert_to_utf8(folder_path):
    extensions = ['.cs', '.js', '.shader', '.compute', '.txt', '.json', '.xml', '.asmdef']
    
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                
                with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                    raw_data = f.read()
                    result = chardet.detect(raw_data)
                    encoding = result['encoding']

                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding=encoding, errors='ignore') as f:
                    content = f.read()
                with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.write(content)
                
                print(f'Converted: {file_path}')

folder_path = r'C:\UnityProjects\Project\Assets'
convert_to_utf8(folder_path)

